# Javascript says number isn't in array?

Tags: javascript, web

```
var colors={
    red: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    green: [14,15,16],
    black: [8,9,10,11,12,13],

}
```

I'm working on a gambling website and this is part of the random prediction code. When i type in console `14 in colors.green` it returns `false` along with any other number in the green array. However any number from `red` or `black` returns `true` with the same console command. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `in` checks to see if the value is a *property name* on the object (or anywhere on the object's prototype). For what you're doing, you should use the `includes` method, which checks whether a value is one of the values of an array:

```js
var colors={
    red: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    green: [14,15,16],
    black: [8,9,10,11,12,13],
};
console.log(colors.green.includes(14));
console.log('red' in colors);
```

If you need to support obsolete browsers and can't use a polyfill, you can check to see if the `indexOf` is -1 instead:

```js
var colors={
    red: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    green: [14,15,16],
    black: [8,9,10,11,12,13],
};
// any number other than -1 means the element was found:
console.log(colors.green.indexOf(15));
console.log(colors.green.indexOf(999));
```

Comment: Good approach except for MSIE. A polyfill is needed, or simply an `indexOf`

Comment: What do you mean, MSIE? I did already explain that `includes` might require a polyfill, or a substitution for `indexOf`

Comment: Internet Explorer was meant. Although I consider it obsolete, it's still in Windows 10 and has surprisingly high usage